# Given a URL in my app, how can I run it through my Routes and inspect its controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am **not** trying to see what the current controller is. The URL in question represents a *previous* request.

E.g.: input `/foo/6`

output: (a hash showing a Controller of `FooController`, action `show`, id `6`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`recognize_path`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/RouteSet/recognize_path)

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path('/foo/6')
```

Output:

```
{:action=>"show", :controller="foo", :id="6"}
```